# Using slimscroll with jquery live() or on()

Tags: slimscroll

I want to use slimscroll plugin on an ajax created page. So I need to use it with jquery live() or on() function. How should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with slimscroll. I couldn't fix it, so I went to Google again. Found this one: https://github.com/LearnBoost/antiscroll.

It claims to use native browser controls, so it should be better than most scrollbar extensions.

Hope this helps you!

**Edit:** Ow, don't forget to call `$('.antiscroll-wrap').antiscroll();` after you edited the content of your page.

**Tip:** For those who use `$.clone()` and find themselves having multiple (non-functional) scrollbars, use this to remove them:

```
var antiscrollWrap = $clone.children(".antiscroll-wrap").first();
var antiscrollInner = $(antiscrollWrap).children(".antiscroll-inner").first();
$(antiscrollWrap).html(antiscrollInner);
```